# adding multiple lines with candlestick in Apexcharts

Tags: apexcharts, candlestick-chart

i am following this demo example on Apexcharts official documentation
https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/candlestick-charts/candlestick-with-line/

it works as it is but if duplicate the line series to display two line along it CandleStick.
The Candlestick gets hidden,
How can i add multiple line charts along with a Candlestick.

This is the code

```
<div><div id="stockPriceChart"></div></div>
<script>             
                                        
                var options = {
                    series: [
                    {
                    name: '50MA',
                    type: 'line',
                    data: [
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538778600000),
                        y: 6610
                        }, {
                        x: new Date(1538782200000),
                        y: 6650
                        }, {
                        x: new Date(1538814600000),
                        y: 6641
                        }, {
                        x: new Date(1538884800000),
                        y: 6670
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    name: '100MA',
                    type: 'line',
                    data: [
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538778600000),
                        y: 6615
                        }, {
                        x: new Date(1538782200000),
                        y: 6600
                        }, {
                        x: new Date(1538814600000),
                        y: 6655
                        }, {
                        x: new Date(1538884800000),
                        y: 6645
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                     {
                    name: 'candle',
                    type: 'candlestick',
                    data: [
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538778600000),
                        y: [6629.81, 6650.5, 6623.04, 6633.33]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538780400000),
                        y: [6632.01, 6643.59, 6620, 6630.11]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538782200000),
                        y: [6630.71, 6648.95, 6623.34, 6635.65]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538784000000),
                        y: [6635.65, 6651, 6629.67, 6638.24]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538785800000),
                        y: [6638.24, 6640, 6620, 6624.47]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538787600000),
                        y: [6624.53, 6636.03, 6621.68, 6624.31]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538789400000),
                        y: [6624.61, 6632.2, 6617, 6626.02]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538791200000),
                        y: [6627, 6627.62, 6584.22, 6603.02]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538793000000),
                        y: [6605, 6608.03, 6598.95, 6604.01]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538794800000),
                        y: [6604.5, 6614.4, 6602.26, 6608.02]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538796600000),
                        y: [6608.02, 6610.68, 6601.99, 6608.91]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538798400000),
                        y: [6608.91, 6618.99, 6608.01, 6612]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538800200000),
                        y: [6612, 6615.13, 6605.09, 6612]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538802000000),
                        y: [6612, 6624.12, 6608.43, 6622.95]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538803800000),
                        y: [6623.91, 6623.91, 6615, 6615.67]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538805600000),
                        y: [6618.69, 6618.74, 6610, 6610.4]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538807400000),
                        y: [6611, 6622.78, 6610.4, 6614.9]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538809200000),
                        y: [6614.9, 6626.2, 6613.33, 6623.45]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538811000000),
                        y: [6623.48, 6627, 6618.38, 6620.35]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538812800000),
                        y: [6619.43, 6620.35, 6610.05, 6615.53]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538814600000),
                        y: [6615.53, 6617.93, 6610, 6615.19]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538816400000),
                        y: [6615.19, 6621.6, 6608.2, 6620]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538818200000),
                        y: [6619.54, 6625.17, 6614.15, 6620]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538820000000),
                        y: [6620.33, 6634.15, 6617.24, 6624.61]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538821800000),
                        y: [6625.95, 6626, 6611.66, 6617.58]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538823600000),
                        y: [6619, 6625.97, 6595.27, 6598.86]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538825400000),
                        y: [6598.86, 6598.88, 6570, 6587.16]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538827200000),
                        y: [6588.86, 6600, 6580, 6593.4]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538829000000),
                        y: [6593.99, 6598.89, 6585, 6587.81]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538830800000),
                        y: [6587.81, 6592.73, 6567.14, 6578]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538832600000),
                        y: [6578.35, 6581.72, 6567.39, 6579]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538834400000),
                        y: [6579.38, 6580.92, 6566.77, 6575.96]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538836200000),
                        y: [6575.96, 6589, 6571.77, 6588.92]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538838000000),
                        y: [6588.92, 6594, 6577.55, 6589.22]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538839800000),
                        y: [6589.3, 6598.89, 6589.1, 6596.08]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538841600000),
                        y: [6597.5, 6600, 6588.39, 6596.25]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538843400000),
                        y: [6598.03, 6600, 6588.73, 6595.97]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538845200000),
                        y: [6595.97, 6602.01, 6588.17, 6602]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538847000000),
                        y: [6602, 6607, 6596.51, 6599.95]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538848800000),
                        y: [6600.63, 6601.21, 6590.39, 6591.02]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538850600000),
                        y: [6591.02, 6603.08, 6591, 6591]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538852400000),
                        y: [6591, 6601.32, 6585, 6592]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538854200000),
                        y: [6593.13, 6596.01, 6590, 6593.34]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538856000000),
                        y: [6593.34, 6604.76, 6582.63, 6593.86]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538857800000),
                        y: [6593.86, 6604.28, 6586.57, 6600.01]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538859600000),
                        y: [6601.81, 6603.21, 6592.78, 6596.25]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538861400000),
                        y: [6596.25, 6604.2, 6590, 6602.99]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538863200000),
                        y: [6602.99, 6606, 6584.99, 6587.81]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538865000000),
                        y: [6587.81, 6595, 6583.27, 6591.96]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538866800000),
                        y: [6591.97, 6596.07, 6585, 6588.39]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538868600000),
                        y: [6587.6, 6598.21, 6587.6, 6594.27]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538870400000),
                        y: [6596.44, 6601, 6590, 6596.55]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538872200000),
                        y: [6598.91, 6605, 6596.61, 6600.02]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538874000000),
                        y: [6600.55, 6605, 6589.14, 6593.01]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538875800000),
                        y: [6593.15, 6605, 6592, 6603.06]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538877600000),
                        y: [6603.07, 6604.5, 6599.09, 6603.89]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538879400000),
                        y: [6604.44, 6604.44, 6600, 6603.5]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538881200000),
                        y: [6603.5, 6603.99, 6597.5, 6603.86]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538883000000),
                        y: [6603.85, 6605, 6600, 6604.07]
                        },
                        {
                        x: new Date(1538884800000),
                        y: [6604.98, 6606, 6604.07, 6606]
                        },
                    ]
                    }],
                    chart: {
                    height: 550,
                    type: 'line',
                    toolbar: {
                        show: false,
                    }
                    },
                    title: {
                    text: 'Price Chart',
                    align: 'left'
                    },
                    stroke: {
                    width: [3, 1]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    custom: [function({seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
                        return w.globals.series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
                    }, function({ seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
                        var o = w.globals.seriesCandleO[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
                        var h = w.globals.seriesCandleH[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
                        var l = w.globals.seriesCandleL[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
                        var c = w.globals.seriesCandleC[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
                        return (
                        ''
                        )
                    }]
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                    }
                    };

                    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#stockPriceChart"), options);
                    chart.render();



            </script>
```

here is a fiddle for the example https://jsfiddle.net/1dtex6pr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `stroke` `width` and `tooltip` `custom` you have values given as array (each value is for a specific series), number of elements there must be equal to number of series.

```
stroke: {
  width: [3, 3, 1]
},
tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  custom: [
  function({seriesIndex,dataPointIndex,w}) {
    return w.globals.series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
  },function({seriesIndex,dataPointIndex,w}) {
    return w.globals.series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
  },
  function({seriesIndex,dataPointIndex,w}) {
    var o = w.globals.seriesCandleO[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
    var h = w.globals.seriesCandleH[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
    var l = w.globals.seriesCandleL[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
    var c = w.globals.seriesCandleC[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
    return `${o}<br>${h}<br>${l}<br>${c}`
  }
  ]
},
```